# Warning message: AdaptV4theme() is deprecated

Tags: material-ui

I'm pretty new to MaterilUI and I recently upgraded my materialUI from V4 to V5. While building the react project, `npm run build`, I get a warning message that my adaptV4theme is being deprecated. To be honest, I don't know what that means. Would someone be able to help me get rid of this warning.

The code:

```
import { adaptV4Theme, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const defaultTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#006565",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#99CBCB",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#006565",
      midground: "#DBEDED",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const lightTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#006565",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#ebebeb",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#ffffff",
      midground: "#e0e0e0",
      textColor: "#000000",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const darkTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#171717",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#171717",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#424242",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#212121",
      midground: "#e3e3e3",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#lightgray",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const greyTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#6c757d",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#8f9ba6",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#6c757d",
      midground: "#dadfe3",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const redTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#dc3545",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#e07e87",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#dc3545",
      midground: "#e3c1c4",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const orangeTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#ff6200",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#ffc380",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#ff8400",
      midground: "#ffdab3",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const blueTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#0059ff",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#75a1ff",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#2f7beb",
      midground: "#c7dcff",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);

export const skyBlueTheme = createTheme(
  adaptV4Theme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#0096ed",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#99CBCB",
      },
    },
    colors: {
      background: "#81d5e6",
      foreground: "#FFFFFF",
      highlight: "#0dcaf0",
      midground: "#daeaed",
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      passColor: "#3bc55f",
      skipColor: "#D3D3D3",
      failColor: "#fd4747",
      pendingColor: "#fec540",
      lightPassColor: "rgb(212, 237, 218)",
      lightPendingColor: "rgb(255, 243, 205)",
      lightFailColor: "rgb(248, 215, 218)",
    },
  })
);
```

Warning:

```
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
MUI: adaptV4Theme() is deprecated.
Follow the upgrade guide on https://mui.com/r/migration-v4#theme.
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove `adaptV4Theme` and you are good to go

```js
export const defaultTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#006565'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#99CBCB',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#006565',
    midground: '#DBEDED',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#006565'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#ebebeb',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#ffffff',
    midground: '#e0e0e0',
    textColor: '#000000',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#171717'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#171717'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#424242',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#212121',
    midground: '#e3e3e3',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#lightgray',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const greyTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#6c757d'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#8f9ba6',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#6c757d',
    midground: '#dadfe3',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const redTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#dc3545'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#e07e87',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#dc3545',
    midground: '#e3c1c4',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const orangeTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff6200'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#ffc380',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#ff8400',
    midground: '#ffdab3',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const blueTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0059ff'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#75a1ff',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#2f7beb',
    midground: '#c7dcff',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})

export const skyBlueTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0096ed'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#99CBCB'
    }
  },
  colors: {
    background: '#81d5e6',
    foreground: '#FFFFFF',
    highlight: '#0dcaf0',
    midground: '#daeaed',
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    passColor: '#3bc55f',
    skipColor: '#D3D3D3',
    failColor: '#fd4747',
    pendingColor: '#fec540',
    lightPassColor: 'rgb(212, 237, 218)',
    lightPendingColor: 'rgb(255, 243, 205)',
    lightFailColor: 'rgb(248, 215, 218)'
  }
})
```

Comment: but what if I want to have the adaptV4theme in my components?

Comment: there is a doc about [migration from mui-v4 to mui-v5](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/migration-v4/) as in the docs mentioned there is no difference from mui-v4 to v-5 just some [input props](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/migration-v4/#variant-prop) and styling as I can see in your code your theme definitions won't affect after updating from v4 to v5 because there is no edge case in your provided code unless there is some conflict in another part of your code...

Comment: doesn't work for me as i m upgrading system from material V4 to mui V5

Comment: what is the error?
can you open a new question?